# crawling on amazon app store

Tags: web-crawler

I want to build a crawler to collect (free) android apps from amazon app store. But I cannot find any download link from its website.
Just want to know if there is a way to crawl amazon app store using a PC (or server). Are there related projects or APIs?

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://crawljax.com